# How to boost query performance with MySQL and Laravel in a nested set

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, indexing

I am using this package https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset in Laravel to query my nested set which is a database of files and directories.

However with 1,000,000 records the queries are very slow. For example I am fetching all directories and files (with pagination):

```
Directory::with('ancestors')->where('name', 'like', '%sample%')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->orderBy('name')->paginate(10);
```

This eloquent method resolves to the following RAW Sql Statements:

First:

> select * from `files` where `name` like '%sample%' order by `created_at` desc, `name` asc limit 10 offset 10;

Second (loading ancestors):

> select * from `files` where ((3952492 between `files`.`_lft` and `files`.`_rgt` and `files`.`id` <> 1976800) or (3952491 between `files`.`_lft` and `files`.`_rgt` and `files`.`id` <> 1976801) or (3952476 between `files`.`_lft` and `files`.`_rgt` and `files`.`id` <> 1976792) or (3952475 between `files`.`_lft` and `files`.`_rgt` and `files`.`id` <> 1976793) or (3951885 between `files`.`_lft` and `files`.`_rgt` and `files`.`id` <> 1976498) or (3951886 between `files`.`_lft` and `files`.`_rgt` and `files`.`id` <> 1976497) or (3950994 between `files`.`_lft` and `files`.`_rgt` and `files`.`id` <> 1976051) or (3950993 between `files`.`_lft` and `files`.`_rgt` and `files`.`id` <> 1976052) or (3950990 between `files`.`_lft` and `files`.`_rgt` and `files`.`id` <> 1976049) or (3950989 between `files`.`_lft` and `files`.`_rgt` and `files`.`id` <> 1976050));

However the query is ultra slow and can take up to 6 seconds to process. Is there a way to improve this with MySQL index?

I had `INDEX(_lgt, _rgt)`. But when doing `EXPLAIN` on the query the `type` is still `ALL` and not `ref`how it should be.

Currently I am very disappointed about the performance of nested set. I thought fetching is fast with that model.

Is there any optimized query I can use for that case?

Comment: even with different approached queries it may improve just a bit since there are lot of comparisons needed. Look into latest feature of `LazyCollection` it may help you boost the speed.

Comment: Is the first query slow or the second? The library itself should create an index on `INDEX(_lgt, _rgt, parent_id)` (no clue if it benefits you, i would just check if it is there.)

Comment: @RolandStarke The second is slower (4-5 seconds), but 1 second for the simple first one is also quite bad. Yep, those index there. But it's not used when running the mentioned eloquent query.

Comment: @MikeRoss I will take a look at that.

Comment: Show the output of explain, without it there's no point to discuss optimization. If you're I/O bound, it might be a case of misconfigured MySQL that can't allocate sufficient memory to play with data using RAM instead of disk. LazyCollection won't help you, it has nothing to do with making MySQL work faster.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (rest of your query) and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE files;   .   SELECT * must put EVERY COLUMN of data from rows SELECTED somewhere during processing.  Using list of COLUMNS you will use rather than * will reduce resources/time required to complete the query and return results.

Comment: Please post TEXT results also of SHOW INDEX FROM files; for our awareness of available indexes and cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

- `LIKE '%...'` -- very slow due to the leading wildcard
- lft/rgt -- inefficient
- pagination using `OFFSET` -- innefficient
- `ORDER BY a DESC, b ASC` -- mixing directions is inefficient

They *cannot* be fixed by improving the indexes.

- Consider switching to `FULLTEXT` and `MATCH...AGAINST`.
- "Remember where you left off" for paginating.
- Both DESC or both ASC.  Still, other things may make this hard to optimize.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can ;):

```
1. Eeable cache in mysql
2. Enable cache in server side (apache2, nginx)
3. Use Redis, memcached, varnish ...
```

But best solution is:

**Buy better and stronger vps server :)**